# Adding reactive object to ref array and breaking the link

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity

Vue3, composition api, newPost is reactive object, posts is ref array.

I gather all fields of new post into newPost, and then on submit - want to add it to posts array like this.

```
      let found = posts.value.findIndex(o => o.id == newPost.id)
      if (found >= 0)
        posts.value[found] = newPost
      else
        posts.value.unshift(newPost)
```

the problem here is that once I start changing newPost object after these lines, posts array reflects those changes as well.

next thing I tried is to use toRaw like this:

```
      let found = posts.value.findIndex(o => o.id == newPost.id)
      if (found >= 0)
        posts.value[found] = toRaw(newPost)
      else
        posts.value.unshift(toRaw(newPost))
```

but problem persists. As soon as I start adding values in newPost object, array posts changes along. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: okay, found it - have to use {...newPost}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.